# Substitutions for Second order Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

Hi guys I have the following system and i am trying to make the appropriate substitutions to break down the system to a first order system of 4 ODE.

$$y''_1 = y_1 + 2y'_2 -  \frac{y_1+\mu}{D_1} - \frac{y_1- \mu }{D_2}  $$

where

$$D_1 =((y_1 +\mu^2)+y^2)^{3/2}$$
and
$$D_2=((y_1-v)^2+y^2_2)^{3/2}$$

and

$$y''_2 = y_2 + 2y'_1 - v \frac{y_1+\mu}{D_1} - \mu \frac{y_1- \mu }{D_2}  $$

I am a bit confused about making the substitutions can anyone help and guide as to how to get the system of 4 first order equations?

Comment: [numerical-methods] so do you want a numerical answer?

Comment: I am trying to understand the substitution required so i can obtain the 4 ODE which must be solved @user12986714. I am hoping you will help me. If the equation was given in terms of just y i understand the substitution but with these two systems i am getting confused as to the substitutions.